# Externalizing log4j.xml in JBoss EAP 7.0.3

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss-eap-7

I have a possibly unique problem. We are using a thirdparty web library that uses log4j to log. Currently, our apps are set up to use the JBoss native logging.(We do this so we can vary the log printouts per environment)
The Thirdparty war file requires us to have a log4j.xml baked into the war its deployed in. Obviously we don't want that.
Here is what I have tried.

- I have tried removing it and seeing if it will use the native jboss logger setup.
- I have tried setting -Dlog4j.configuration to the path of the log4j.xml file.
- I tried setting a system property of the jboss eap in the standalone-full file with the same name.

I dont have access to the source code, but I can decompile.

Any ideas?

Comment: That does sound unique and if you figure out the answer yourself or via the JBoss Forums help you might answer your own question.  My only advice is to see if you can get some help in the [JBoss Forums](https://developer.jboss.org/places).  Good luck!

Comment: What makes the log4j.xml required?